# animation MOVE - same speed

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4, mxml

I have a simple `MOVE` animation effect on my component in MXML. I need this animation to run with same speed (not accelerate at start, not slowly at the end animation (its default). I need one speed. Is this possible as set some parameter in `MOVE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an easing function. In this case you'll be looking for Linear.easeIn or Linear.ease out

Some links:
[Adobe - Easing Functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf5fdc3-7fe2.html)

Comment: Also check out http://www.jamesward.com/easingFunctionFun/easingFunctionFun.html
I'm new so I can't post 2 links in my first answer